# Java Android CalendarView selectedDateChanged not updating

Tags: java, android, gregorian-calendar, calendarview

I have a CalendarView that allows a user to select a date and enter activities.

I have a method that is called whenever the selected date is changed as follows:

```
private void selectedDateChanged(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
        //note: _Calendar is set to the view when activity loads hence the
        //the reason for not using view.getDate();
        Long timeSinceEpoch = _Calendar.getDate();

        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeSinceEpoch);

        System.out.println(String.format("With gregorian calendar \n Day: %s \n Month: %s \n Year: %s",
                calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.MONTH, calendar.YEAR));

    }
```

The method is being called everytime the date selected changes, the issue is the GregorianCalendar is not updating each time the method is called. Whenever I select a new day,

```
I/System.out: With gregorian calendar 
I/System.out:  Day: 5 
I/System.out:  Month: 2 
I/System.out:  Year: 1
```

is printed out and does not update when a new date is selected.

I can't figure out how to force the GregorianCalendar to update and the javadoc for CalendarView says that getDate() should return the currently selected date in milliseconds since unix epoch

Comment: why not use the passed params `year`, `month`, `dayOfMonth`?

Comment: @petey I am going to need to get the date from other methods that don't have those parameters. This was just a convenient place to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`, `Calendar.MONTH`, and `CALENDAR.YEAR` are not fields with that information, but integers representing which you are looking for when you call `Calendar.get();`

So fixing this was rather simple was I learned that, the proper code is:

```
private void selectedDateChanged(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
        //note: _Calendar is set to the view when activity loads hence the
        //the reason for not using view.getDate();
        Long timeSinceEpoch = _Calendar.getDate();

        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeSinceEpoch);

        //Notice instead of calling cal.DAY_OF_MONTH directly
        //I now call calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        System.out.println(String.format("With gregorian calendar \n Day: %s \n Month: %s \n Year: %s",
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(String.format("With gregorian calendar \n Day: %s \n Month: %s \n Year: %s",
            dayOfMonth, month, year));
```

Comment: I'm intentionally not using the parameters because I will need to be able to get the day, month, and year from other methods where I will only have access to the CalendarView